# User Login form with visual C# & SQL

Tags: c#, sql, authentication

This is my code for user log in. i want to match the user input with SQL. Where emp_ID, password, and the user type(Admin, employee) should equal to the user input. this code is not working properly. so when i choose what ever the user type, its says access denied

```
try
        {
            myconnection.Open();
            cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from loging  where emp_ID = '" + username.Text + "' and password = '" + password.Text + "' and user_type = '"+label4.Text+"'", myconnection);
            myreader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            int count = 0;
            while (myreader.Read()) 
            {
                count = count + 1;
            }
            if (count == 1 || comboBox1.Text == label4.Text )
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Access Granted");
            }

            else if (count > 1)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Access denied");
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Access denied");
            }


            myconnection.Close();
        }
```

Comment: not working properly means? any spec ific error? what is `comboBox1` in your code?

Comment: You haven't explained what problem are you facing, but this code is a suitable target for SQL injection. Use command parameters instead.

Comment: Don't use inline SQL values, it makes your program vulnerable to SQL injection attacks.

Answer (score 0):

though you have not explained the exact problem you are facing, i would like to suggest you few basic things which will provide more security.

**Suggestion 1:** your `SELECT` query is open to `SQL-Injection` Attacks so i would suggest you to use `Parameterised queries` to avoid them.

**Suggestion 2:** if you want to only `count` total number of rows returned by `SELECT` query, you can use following query to simplify the task:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TableName;
```

the above query will return the total number of rows returned.

**Suggestion 3:** in your code you dont need to have two else blocks as both are similar . so you can remove one of them to increase readability of your code.

**Note :** as i already asked in comments bove,if you can tell us what exactly `Combobox1` is in your code and also its relation with `label4`, it would help us to resolve your issue.

**Complete Code:**

```
    try
    {
        myconnection.Open();
        cmd = new SqlCommand("select count(*) from loging  where emp_ID =@emp_ID and password =@password and user_type = @user_type", myconnection);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@emp_ID",username);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password",password);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@user_type",label4.Text);

        int count = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());            
        if (count == 1 || comboBox1.Text == label4.Text )
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Access Granted");
        }
        else 
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Access denied");
        }
        myconnection.Close();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Some advises on security:

- don't concatenate SQL query strings, use parameters instead to avoid SQL injection;
- don't use the standard password text box, there's a c# memory-pinning implementation that protects you against memory-swapping the password unto disk;
- don't just count the lines you get but require the DB to send you an actual information that you have to match;
- don't save passwords in a database, hash them with a random salt against rainbow attacks;
- don't use Math.Random() but the cryptographic RandomNumberGenerator class.

Maybe some 2-3 other advises should be given, but my eyes are already bleeding...